# CSS Dropdown Not Working on iPad when Scrolling is Needed

Tags: html, css, ipad, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS dropdown menu with mouseout and mouseover events. On an iPad or iPhone the menu is automatically closed when scrolling, and refuses to open any links unless the menu is short enough to not scroll. Can anyone think of a fix?

http://willosteen.com/flvec/index_ipad.html

The 'Select a County' list is not functioning properly.

Comment: On the Apple devices you could lose the fancy UL/LI + CSS style and make it a regular SELECT element. Then it would work using the devices native operation.

Comment: Would there be a way to retain the mouseout and mouseover events if using a regular select element?

Comment: They wouldn't be required for the iPad/iPhone version as you don't have those events. You could keep them for the desktop version.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I added the following script to the start of the document to use the select element for mobile browsers (if anyone else needs it). I appreciate the help!

    <script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || 
 (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) ||
 (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1) || 
 (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('android') != -1)) {
  document.location = "index1.html";
 } // ]]>
    </script>

Comment: You can use whatever method (mobile detection or media query) to hide the ul on iphone and show the select, as Billy Moat suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it an onclick dropdown for touch devices and keep the fancy styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution I found. Adding the following line inside to your span, li or anchor causes the iPad to behave like safari on mac and onclick open the dropdown

```
onClick="return true"
```

See it in action here - http://www.naturalsal.it/